# Dygraph Output Disconnecting Between Adjacent Data Points

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I am graphing a `Dygraph` output in a Shiny App, and there are sections of my charts that are not connecting the points between data points.  Does anyone know why certain segments in between time steps in a `Dygraph` would disconnect?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: is you time appropriately formatted?

Comment: I solved this problem by using connectSeparatedPoints.  `dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"), connectSeparatedPoints = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the `connectSeparatedPoints` option for Dygraphs.  For example, here is the code I am using to show my dygraph:

```
dygraph(component, main = "Temperature Rise Data Plot") %>%
      dyAxis("y", label = "Temp (F)") %>%
      dyAxis("x", label = "Time (min)")%>%
      dyRangeSelector() %>%
      dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"), connectSeparatedPoints = TRUE)
```